# How do you share gRPC proto definitions between services

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, grpc

I am specifying a number of independent **gRPC** services that will all be hosted out of the same server process. Each service is defined in its own protobuf file. These are then run through the **gRPC** tools to give me the target language (c# in my case) in which I can then implement my server and client.

Each of those separate APIs uses a number of common elements, things like error response enumerations, the *Empty* message type (which seems to be available in the **gRPC** *WellKnownTypes*; but I cannot see how I include that either so I defined my own).

At the moment I end up with each proto building duplicate enums and classes into their own namespace. Though I know I can share the definitions in a common proto file and include that; I do not see how to end up with only a single code gen of these into a common namespace. Though this works it would be neater to keep it to one set; it may also have issues later in conversion and equivalence if doing things like aggregating errors across services.

I assume I am missing something as my reading of things such as the *WellKnownTypes* namespace suggests that this should be possible but, as mentioned before, I don't see how I refer to that in the Proto either.

SO seems pretty light on **gRPC** for the moment so my searches are not turning up much, and I am new to this so any pointers?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#other might be a thing for you.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Protocol buffers solve this problem by using a different `package` identifier.  Each message will be placed in a different Protocol buffer specific package, which is independent of the C# namespace.   For example:

```
// common.proto
syntax "proto3";
package my.api.common;

option csharp_namespace = "My.Api.Common";

message Shared {
  // ...
}
```

And then in the service specific file:

```
// service1.proto
syntax "proto3";
package my.api.service1;

import "common.proto";

option csharp_namespace = "My.Api.Service1";

message Special {
    my.api.common.Shared shared = 1;
}
```

You need to make sure there is only one copy of the common proto, otherwise they could get out of sync.  You can put common messages in the `common.proto` file and reference them from each of your specific other proto files.

Comment: I am sooooo sorry it took me so long to get back to verifying this. Was dragged onto another task.